# rCharts -- chart resize doesn't occur for nvd3 nPlot

Tags: r, rcharts, nvd3.js

Probably just a small bug in implementation, but it seems nPlots won't resize themselves after a change in window width, despite `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)` as the default behavior in the NVD3 plots implemented in rCharts.
I'm not sure if this calls for an example, but you can see the problem with any call to `nPlot()`, including this:

```
require(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=runif(n=20))

n1 <- nPlot(
  y~x,
  data=df,
  type="lineChart"
)
n1$yAxis( axisLabel = "Random Number" )
n1$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
n1
```

Is there a way to turn on resizing and I'm just missing it, or should I file this under 'issues' on the github page?

Comment: I think it might have to do with the `div` the chart is contained in. I will take a look at what needs to be done for responsiveness.

Comment: Hi, is it fixed this?

Comment: I don't think this is fixed in the current release, but I got around it by manually adjusting the CSS for the plot's div in my shiny app. Not sure how to fix it in another context sadly.

Comment: Does this kind of bug fixed yet or not ?